# Convert the dictionary into tuple and printing it in reverse order

Tags: python, dictionary

I am having values in dict for example
{"AR":True,"VF":False,"Siss":True}

Now I am only extracting the keys having value TRUE, so I am only getting the output AR and Siss, I am trying to save this output in tuple and now wants to print them out in reverse order like ("Siss","AR").

Below is my code snippet, When I convert it into tuple its showing me output in form of character instead of string

```
for i in dic:
        if dic[i]==True:
            t = tuple(i)
            print (t)
            Reverse(t)
def Reverse(tuples): 
    new_tup = tuples[::-1] 
    return new_tup
```

How to change those characters into words/strings ?

Comment: Your Reverse function does not reverse in place. It returns the reversed tuple, so you need to assign it to `t` in the calling code. Also, you should almost never write code like `if x == True:` (or False). Instead, write `if x:` or `if not x:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple step-wise approach that uses a list as an intermediate, fills it with the appropriate keys from your dictionary, reverses the list, then converts it into a tuple.

```
dic = {"AR":True,"VF":False,"Siss":True}

lst = []
for key in dic:
        if dic[key]: (# ==True is redundant)
            lst.append(key)

lst.reverse()
result = tuple(lst)

print(result)
#('Siss', 'AR')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it easily by transverse the dictionary in reversed order and filter out the non True values.

```
d = {'AR': True, 'VF': False, 'Siss': True}
print(tuple(k for k,v in reversed(d.items()) if v is True))

('Siss', 'AR')
```

Comment: Why its giving me character when I type `t = tuple(i)` ? What wrong in my approach, Can you please explain

Comment: @AHF python doesn't have characters as such. If you turn a string into a tuple, each element of the tuple is a length-1 string.

Answer (score 1):

A functional approach:

```py
dictionary = { "AR": True, "VF": False, "Siss": True }
filtered = filter(lambda kv: kv[1], reversed(dictionary.items()))
just_key = map(lambda kv: kv[0], filtered)

print(list(just_key))
```

It works by:

1. `reversed`-ing the key-value pairs in the dictionary
2. `filter`ing the dictionary's items, removing all the key-value pairs that are `False`.
3. Just preserving the key with a `map`

Comment: Why its giving me character when I type `t = tuple(i)` ?

Comment: Because in your example, `i` is the key, e.g., `AR`, `VF`, `Siss`. This is the same as doing `tuple("AR")`, which gives `("A", "R")`. If you need the word, just don't convert it into a tuple.